# why my shell does work well with -a in if condition?

Tags: shell

This is my code:

```
    echo $1  $2
    if [ "Release"!="$2" -a "Debug"!="{$2}" ]; then
        echo "error! the arg of -c must be \"Release\" or \"Debug\" !"
        exit 1
    fi
    XCODECONFIG="$2";
```

when I input

```
    ./build.sh a Release
```

the output is:

```
    a Release
    error! the arg of -c must be "Release" or "Debug" !
```

it prints "error! the arg of -c must be "Release" or "Debug" !" why doesn't go on to XCODECONFIG="$2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be spaces around `!=`:

```
[ "Release" != "$2" -a "Debug" != "{$2}" ]
```

When you write your expression without spaces, it is syntaticaly correct, but means other thing. It looks like:

```
[ STR1 -a STR2 ]
```

In your case, there are != inside, but that means nothing; that is anyway just strings; each string is evaluated as true, and `True -a True` will be also evaluated as true.

Answer (score 2):

Spaces matters in shell script, try:

`if [ "Release" != "$2" -a "Debug" != "{$2}" ]; then`

Otherwise your expressions would just be evaluated to two chunks of string which both has truthy values, thus the if executed